# Services without a process

Tags: processes

In the Settings > Apps screen, under "Running", a few apps are listed as having as active (i.e. a service is running) despite having zero running processes and taking no memory.

Why are they in this state? Are they waiting for some kind of event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, these are cached services. They are used to boost up service start time. From [Android Developers - Processes and Threads (as of Feb 13, 2015)](https://web.archive.org/web/20150213003242/http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)

> 5. Empty process
>
>    A process that doesn't hold any active application components. The only reason to keep this kind of process alive is for caching purposes, to improve startup time the next time a component needs to run in it. The system often kills these processes in order to balance overall system resources between process caches and the underlying kernel caches.
>
> Android ranks a process at the highest level it can, based upon the importance of the components currently active in the process. For example, if a process hosts a service and a visible activity, the process is ranked as a visible process, not a service process.
>
> In addition, a process's ranking might be increased because other processes are dependent on it—a process that is serving another process can never be ranked lower than the process it is serving. For example, if a content provider in process A is serving a client in process B, or if a service in process A is bound to a component in process B, process A is always considered at least as important as process B.
>
> Because a process running a service is ranked higher than a process with background activities, an activity that initiates a long-running operation might do well to start a service for that operation, rather than simply create a worker thread—particularly if the operation will likely outlast the activity. For example, an activity that's uploading a picture to a web site should start a service to perform the upload so that the upload can continue in the background even if the user leaves the activity. Using a service guarantees that the operation will have at least "service process" priority, regardless of what happens to the activity. This is the same reason that broadcast receivers should employ services rather than simply put time-consuming operations in a thread.